# UIActionSheet unrecognized selector error

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I tried compiling and running this simple code but it's throwing error

```
- (void)doSomething
{
 UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
          initWithTitle:@"Are you sure?"
          delegate:self
          cancelButtonTitle:@"No Way"
          destructiveButtonTitle:@"Yes, I'm Sure!"
          otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
 [actionSheet release];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
 if (buttonIndex == 0)
 {
  NSLog(@"ok");


    }
}
```

This is the error thrown:

```
-[__NSCFData actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d6df80
2010-10-25 16:07:36.120 iota[31172:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d6df80'
```

The interesting thing is that it is not running as part of a bigger code but runs fine on a standalone basis.

Comment: in that case, post the code with which its failing.. cause, clearly the problem is somewhere in that code..

Comment: @lukya got it sorted read below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The instance that it's sending the `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` message to seems to think that it's of type `NSData` (of `CFData`). This suggests to me that the instance of `self` has probably been deallocated before the button is pressed.

Adding the delegate doesn't retain it, so you need to keep it around as long as the `UIActionSheet` is going to be visible.

Comment: Stephen Darlington..you are such a darling...i was popping to root view controller before handling the action sheet... thanks a lot man..